# A Switch Within A Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, html, function, switch-statement, onblur

I am in the process of writing a contact form.

I have two Javascript functions in the head (will move them later, but that is another question).

The first function, `Validate()`,  for the onblur event is not working. 
The second function, `formValidate()`, for the onsubmit event works.

I want to use a switch statement in a javascript function to use in an html onblur event.

The Javascript:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Validate()
        {
            // create array containing textbox elements
            var input = [document.getElementById('fname'), document.getElementById('lname'), document.getElementById('email1'), document.getElementById('email12'), document.getElementById('message')];

               for(var i = 0; i<input.length; i++)
            // loop through each element to see if value is empty
            {
                if(input[i].value == '')
                {
                        switch (ID){

                        case 'fname':
                        alert ('enter you first name');
                        break;
                        case 'lname' :
                        alert ('enter your last name');
                        break;
                        case 'email1':
                        alert ('enter your email address');
                        break;
                        case 'email2':
                        alert ('enter your email address');
                        break;
                        case 'message':
                        alert ('write your message');
                        break;                          
                    }                   
                }                   
            }            
         }

function formValidate()
        {
            // create array containing textbox elements
            var inputs = [document.getElementById('fname'), document.getElementById('lname'), document.getElementById('email1'), document.getElementById('email2'), document.getElementById('message')];

            var error;

            for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)
            // loop through each element to see if value is empty
            {
                if(inputs[i].value == '')
                {
                    error = 'Please complete all fields.';
                    alert(error);
                    return false;
                    }
            }
         }
</script>
</head>
```

The html:

```
<form onsubmit="return formValidate()"  action="mailto:admin@sfasc.com.au" method="post"  id="contactForm" >
        <fieldset>
          <dl>
            <dt> First Name:</dt>
            <dd>
              <input class="input" type="text"  name="fname" id="fname" onblur="Validate()" />
            </dd>
            <dt> Last Name:</dt>
            <dd>
              <input class="input" type="text"  name="lname" id="lname" onblur="Validate()"/>
            </dd>
            <dt> Email Address:</dt>
            <dd>
              <input class="input" type="text"  name="email1"  id="email1" onblur="Validate()"/>
            </dd>
            <dt> Email Address:</dt>
            <dd>
              <input class="input" type="text"  name="email2"  id="email2" onblur="Validate()"/>
            </dd>
            <dt> Message:</dt>
            <dd>
              <textarea  name="address" id="address" rows="10" cols="10" onblur="Validate()"></textarea>
            </dd>
            <dd>
              <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"  />
            </dd>
          </dl>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

I have tried removing the second function, but it makes no difference.
I am only learning.

Can anyone, please, tell me what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't work, `ID` is not defined anywhere:

```
switch (ID) {
```

You should replace it with this:

```
switch(input[i].id) {
```

You should do some debugging, the error would surely appear in the console!